# How can I remove empty strings from custom dropdown?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom dropdown menu of filters that you can add, delete or rename. But if you delete a tag it leaves an empty string and I'm having trouble removing those from the dropdown.

Here's the dropdown:

```
<select v-model="tagFilter">
  <option value="">
        Select Tag
  </option>
  <option v-for="cocktail in uniqueTags">
    <option :key="cocktail.id" v-if="cocktail.tag !== null && cocktail.tag !== ''">
      {{ cocktail.tag }}
    </option>
  </option> 
</select>
<button id="filter-and-sort-button" v-if="tagFilter !== ''" v-on:click="tagFilter = ''">
  Clear Tag
</button>
```

Computed properties for the tag filters and removing duplicates:

```
computed: {
  filteredCocktails() {
    return (
      this.cocktails
        // tag filter
        .filter((cocktail) => {
          if (this.tagFilter === "") {
            return cocktail;
          } else {
            return cocktail.tag === this.tagFilter;
          }
        })
    );
  },
  uniqueTags() {
  return this.cocktails.reduce((seed, current) => {
    return Object.assign(seed, {
      [current.tag]: current
      });
    }, {});
  },
},
```

I also tried using a method but that didn't work either:

```
  removeEmptyTags(cocktail) {
    if (![null, ""].includes(cocktail.tag))
      return true
  },
```

I removed duplicate tags and tags with null values though, just not tags with empty strings.

Comment: Ideally when the tag is deleted it does not leave behind an empty string but is completely removed.  Can you show your "delete tag" code?

Comment: You "delete" a tag through updating params, so just deleting whatever you had typed

Comment: I'm not sure what params you mean, or where tags are typed.  Probably in some code you've not shown.  Regardless, two mistakes pop out.  `<option>` inside another `<option>`.  Realize that an element with a v-for on it is literally the element that is rendered in the loop. It is good you have the v-if and v-for on different elements, but double option elements is a mistake.  Change the outer one to `<template>`. Template tags are never rendered but will still be looped producing multiple of the inner `<option>` element.

Comment: Other mistake is thinking a computed or method is even needed.  Just use `cocktails` array.  `<template v-for="cocktail in cocktails">`.  The v-if will take care of not rendering any null or empty string tags.

Comment: Thanks, adding <template> worked. I'm using computed to remove duplicate tags